Density of a Lattice.
For an integer $N \ge 1$ denote by $K_N$ the number of pairs of integers $(m, n)$
with $|m|, |n| \le N$ such that the straight line from the origin to $(m, n)$
does not intersect any other lattice point $\{ (m, n) : m, n ∈ Z\} \setminus \{(0, 0)\} $. compute the limit $(2N)^{-2}K_N $ as $N$ tends to infinity.
Where to start? How to estimate $K_N$?!

If I'm not mistaking: there are not lattice points on the line segment $(0,0)-(m,n)$ when $\gcd(m,n)=1$.
